# How to change all the cells value in the selected column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write some code that will change all the cells in the selected column under some conditions.

My code can change the selected cell but crushes when I try to change all the selected column.

```
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet  
Dim MyRange As Range

Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet  
Set MyRange = Selection

If MyRange.Cells.Value = "Clothes" Then    
    MyRange.Cells.Value = 2
ElseIf MyRange.Cells.Value = "Extra" Then
    MyRange.Value = 3
ElseIf MyRange.Cells.Value = "Shoes" Then
    MyRange.Value = 1
End If
```

It works fine when I'm trying to change all the column color for example, but not on the value.

Comment: You need a loop through the cells of that (selected) column and process each cell on it's own. Give it a try there are many tutorials how to loop through the data of a column.

Comment: thanks!now works great when loop throw the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop for that, try this?

```
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet  
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim TargetCell As Range 

Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet  
Set MyRange = Selection

For Each TargetCell In MyRange.Cells

    If TargetCell.Value = "Clothes" Then    
        TargetCell.Value = 2
    ElseIf TargetCell.Value = "Extra" Then
        TargetCell.Value = 3
    ElseIf TargetCell.Value = "Shoes" Then
        TargetCell.Value = 1
    End If

Next TargetCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through selected cells and use a `Select Case` statement (alternatively to your `If … ElseIf` statement).

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Selection

Dim TargetCell As Range 
For Each TargetCell In MyRange.Cells
    Select Case TargetCell.Value 
        Case "Clothes"  
            TargetCell.Value = 2
        Case "Extra"
            TargetCell.Value = 3
        Case "Shoes" 
            TargetCell.Value = 1
    End Select
Next TargetCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help,works great.i tried this code:
      Dim found As Boolean

```
  found = False

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

     If ActiveCell.Value = "Clothes" Then
      ActiveCell.Value = 2
      ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "Shoes" Then
       ActiveCell.Value = 1
      ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "Extra" Then
       ActiveCell.Value = 3
        found = True

     End If

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).
Using select is the worst of all these solutions. Please have a look at the other answers. Your code is much faster if you don't use `.Select`!